# ASP.NET MVC Show success message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is an example method I have that deletes a record from my app:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "news-admin")]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var ArticleToDelete = (from a in _db.ArticleSet where a.storyId == id select a).FirstOrDefault();
    _db.DeleteObject(ArticleToDelete);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

What I would like to do is show a message on the Index view that says something like: "Lorem ipsum article has been deleted" how would I do this? Thanks

Here is my current Index method, just in case:

```
    // INDEX
    [HandleError]
    public ActionResult Index(string query, int? page)
    {
        // build the query
        var ArticleQuery = from a in _db.ArticleSet select a;
        // check if their is a query
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            ArticleQuery = ArticleQuery.Where(a => a.headline.Contains(query));
            //msp 2011-01-13 You need to send the query string to the View using ViewData
            ViewData["query"] = query;
        }
        // orders the articles by newest first
        var OrderedArticles = ArticleQuery.OrderByDescending(a => a.posted);
        // takes the ordered articles and paginates them using the PaginatedList class with 4 per page
        var PaginatedArticles = new PaginatedList<Article>(OrderedArticles, page ?? 0, 4);
        // return the paginated articles to the view
        return View(PaginatedArticles);
    }
```

Comment: I created a nuget package that helps with sending (error, warning, info and success) messages from controller to view that's Bootstrap ready: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BootstrapNotifications/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way would be to use TempData:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "news-admin")]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var ArticleToDelete = (from a in _db.ArticleSet where a.storyId == id select a).FirstOrDefault();
    _db.DeleteObject(ArticleToDelete);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    TempData["message"] = ""Lorem ipsum article has been deleted";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and inside the `Index` action you could fetch this message from TempData and make use of it. For example you could pass it as a property of your view model which will be passed to the view so that it can show it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var message = TempData["message"];
    // TODO: do something with the message like pass to the view
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Message = TempData["message"] as string;
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and inside the strongly typed view:

```
<div><%: Model.Message %></div>
```

Comment: Okay sounds interesting. 1.) How do I pass it into the View. 2.) How do I then show it in the View. Thanks :)

Comment: You define a ViewModel with a string property which will be assigned to this message. Then you strongly type your view to this view model and inside the view you simply use `<%: Model.Message %>`. Or you do something very ugly inside the controller action `ViewData["message"] = message;` and inside the view: `<%: ViewData["message"] %>` (I repeat this is ugly and I don't recommend it, ViewData just sucks).

Comment: I don't quite understand the ViewModel and strongly typing it. Could you show an example in the code above? Thanks.

Comment: Where does this go? Inside my Controller? `public class MyViewModel { public string Message { get; set; } }`

Comment: Also my Index already has a return View so how would I pass the message into it? I've shown my Index method in my Original Question. Thanks.

Comment: any updates as im confused about how to pass that model into the view if im already passing my paginatedarticles into it? Thanks.

Comment: Then you could add a string property to your existing view model and use that.

Comment: I ended up just using the ViewData :)