# How to show alert message in mvc 4 controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried show a alert box in mvc controller by if-else condition.But alert box does not display.Where is my mistake ?

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userId"].ToString());

    if (WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (userId == 90043) 
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "You are not authorized.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "alert message"? Be aware that the code inside controllers executes on a server, without (direct) user supervision. It does not represent the end result (web page) that the user sees and interacts with. Furthermore, since this is not a WinForms project, you can't display message boxes. It makes no sense. If you do want to display a JavaScript `alert`, do so from within the `Index`view.

Comment: Hi Andrei I want to show a alert  before RedirectToAction if userId is not equal to 90043

Comment: @user3107343 you can not

Comment: To whom? Who must see this message? Is it just for debugging purposes?

Comment: where are you using from TempData["Message"]  in client side ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot show an alert from a controller. There is one way communication from the client to the server.The server can therefore not tell the client to do anything. The client requests and the server gives a response.

You therefore need to use javascript when the response returns to show a messagebox of some sort.

OR

using jquery on the button that calls the controller action

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitButton").on("click",function()
  {
   alert('Your Message');
  });

});
<script>
```

Answer (score 60):

```
TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Change succesfully');</script>";
@Html.Raw(TempData["msg"])
```

Answer (score 24):

Use this:

```
return JavaScript(alert("Hello this is an alert"));
```

or:

```
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Thanks for Feedback!');</script>");
```

Comment: Thanks man! Second one works for me as:

   public ActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        //...
        //...

        return new ContentResult() { Content = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Thanks for Feedback!');</script>" };
      } 
    }

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to display alerts from the controller. Because MVC views and controllers are entirely separated from each other. You can only display information in the view only. So it is required to pass the information to be displayed from controller to view by using either `ViewBag`, `ViewData` or `TempData`. If you are trying to display the content stored in `TempData["Message"]`, It is possible to perform in the view page by adding few javascript lines.

```
<script>
  alert(@TempData["Message"]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteBlog")" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure want to delete blog?');">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Message: 
\n" + "Hi!" + " .');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not typical alert box, but I hope it may help someone.

There is [this expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21146524/9233618) that enables you to show notifications inside HTML page using bootstrap.

It is very easy to implement and it works fine. Here is [a github page](https://github.com/uacaps/BootstrapNotifications) for the project including some demo images.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
TempData["err"] = "Something happenend";
```

In your view

```
var error =  '@TempData["err"]';
if(error){
    alert(error);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).