# More messages in TempData

Tags: asp.net-core, tempdata

currently I'm in the middle of one project and I would like to send success/warning/error/info messages from controller to view.

This is my code:

```
public static void AddNotification(this Controller controller, string messageType, string message)
    {
        ICollection<string> messages = controller.TempData[NotificationsKey] as ICollection<string>;
        if (messages == null)
            controller.TempData[NotificationsKey] = (messages = new HashSet<string>());
        KeyValuePair<string,string> keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<string, string> (messageType, message);
        //            messages.Add(keyValuePairs);
        string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyValuePair, Formatting.None);
        try
        {
            messages.Add(serializedObject);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

(Just for info - this code I have found on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337914/success-message-from-controller-to-view))

My problem is, that if I want to add second message, then error occurs:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size.
>   System.SZArrayHelper.Add(T value)

Can you please help me? How to solve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean `add second message` and where does the error occur? I tried your above code and it all works well based on the SO link...Could you explain the steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I mean when one message is already in messages (i.e. Success message, that user was logged in was not shown => it is still in TempData and I would like to add there another message. Then it crashed with error above.

Afterwards I have solved the issue by exchanging ICollection<string> type with List<string> type...